# Different CSS style behaviour depending on the image style

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have some text with images aligned left or right, wrapped by text. Their alignment is hardcoded in the .html file like this: `<img style="float:left" ... />`. When the image is aligned left, I want to have some space to the rigth (margin: 0 1rem 0 0). And vice versa, if the image is on the right, I want to have some space to the left (margin: 0 0 0 1rem). See the scheme below. I need to do this by styles in styles.css file, something like:

```
figure[style="float: left;"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
figure[style="float: right;"] {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Please anyone help me with it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Ahmad Alfy, the problem is solved. I just had to remove the unnecessary white spaces: (float: left -> float:left). Also, Ahmad, thanks for the other lifehacks! So, we can close the discussion now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the selector you write is that it should be identical to the way it's written in HTML (same letter cases, same white spaces ... etc).

So according to the HTML you wrote, you should modify it to the following

```css
figure[style="float:left"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

figure[style="float:right"] {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Or you can use something like the following

```css
figure[style*="float:left"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

figure[style*="float:right"] {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

The asterisk means that the style contain `float:left` or `float:right` and apply the required style.

There is something that comes to my mind <s>but I never tested</s> it's working fine, I tested it.

```css
figure[style*="float"][style*="left"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

figure[style*="float"][style*="right"] {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

This should test that the selector contain both combination (float, right or left). Didn't test it though.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ahmad! You've solved my problem! I've just removed the space (float: left -> float:left), and it now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can do attribute-based selectors, I never tried doing it with styles, but it's a bad idea. Even if it works, it assumes that no other style is applied on your tag. It is highly unreliable. Tried

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a[style="color:red;"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The link with target="_blank" gets a yellow background:</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
<a href="http://www.disney.com" target="_blank" style="color:red;">disney.com</a>
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org" target="_top">wikipedia.org</a>

</body>
</html>
```

and it appears to be working (the yellow background is successfully applied) in FireFox. However, this is a very bad idea, it would be much wiser to create these CSS classes:

```
.fl {
    float: left;
}

.fr {
    float: right;
}
```

Refactor your hard-coded styles to use these classes instead and use class-based selectors afterwards. So, the thing you want to achieve is achievable, but not recommendable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tiny issue you may didn't notice which is **semicolon** because in css file you should write the exact css selector as it appears in html attribute, see below for example:

```css
p[style="color: red;"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
p[style="color: red"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: red;">This will be yellow bg!</p>
<p style="color: red">This will be green bg!</p>
```

**BUT** as @Lajos Arpad mention in his answer, *it's a bad idea* to style your css depending on html attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer.
If for some reason padding like this doesn't work:

```
div {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

else I would add styling to the paragraph itself and not just the image.

You could also use different classes for different images:

```
  figure1[style="float: left;"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
figure2[style="float: right;"] {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```